# One public IP and need two servers to be accessible from Internet

Tags: networking

So we are basically implementing a net for our new business. I have no experience with networks, so I am a little bit confused. Besides the LAN computers, we have two servers: one will be handling all mail and the other one will host our website. However, we just bought one public IP.

So, I have done tests and I was able to set it up so that we can access the web server from Internet. But then the mail server is not visible. How can I configure my network in order to be able to access both servers from internet?

We have not decided which OS we are going to use... so I am not trying to get specific information about how to configure this in the OS, but a overall idea of how to do this.

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing some sort of port forwarding on your router/firewall? If so could you not just point port 80 to your web server and port 25 to your mail server?

Answer (score 3):

> I have no experience with networks, so I am a little bit confused.

From a big picture perspective, I would say hire a local contractor to help you with your setup and decision-making as far as your network configuration is concerned.  A badly-configured network can be costly in both real dollars and opportunity cost if it was unreliable and or compromised; both are a real possibility if not setup correctly.

Technically, there's usually few reasons why you'd want to host your own Web server in-house; why not get a micro instance from Amazon EC2 or even go with shared hosting for now?  Let somebody else handle the infrastructure while you can focus on growing your business.

And actually, why bring mail in-house?  Google Apps for your Domain is free for up to 5 users and supports open protocols like IMAP, POP3 and a very good Web interface (just like gmail if you're not familiar with it) so down the road if you wanted to setup an in-house mail server you could.

If you want the Microsoft stack, Office Live 365 is a cloud-based solution that gives you all the collaboration/Unified Communications of Office and Exchange, but at a low monthly fee.

If you truly must have an in-house Web and mail server, consider setting up a DMZ interface on your firewall with filtering so that your mail and Web server are not on the same network as your LAN*.  You can add rules to permit access to the DMZ from the LAN (but not vice-versa), but by isolating your LAN from your exposed Internet-facing servers, you're protecting yourself in case they get compromised.  You don't need another static IP either: you can use DNAT (port forwarding) to expose certain ports on your servers to the outside world; this is a very common setup for small deployments.

*this gets tricky when you have an Active Directory domain setup and only one Exchange Server.

Answer (score 1):

Get another IP. Other than that, you can either set up some kind of router before your servers and configure them to do some port forwarding, or you can configure one of the machines to do this. In this case, the machine needs at least two network ports.

Since it is likely that you already have a router in front of your network, I guess port forwarding from the router is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Invariably, you've got some type of router/firewall device sitting at the ingress/egress of your network that connects you to your ISP. What you need to do is to find out whether or not that device can NAT and forward web traffic (typically port 80) to your web server and NAT and forward email traffic (port 25) to your email server. If your current router/firewall doesn't have that capability then you'll need to get a device that does.

All in all it should be fairly straight forward getting it set up.

What model/make router/firewall do you have?